# Supporting events on sock.js

Tags: migration, socket.io, sockjs, custom-events

I'm thinking of migrating from Socket.io to Sock.js.

But my code is heavily based on custom events, and I'm wondering how to add them on Sock.js, since it doesn’t' support this feature out of the box.

What would you find as the less time-consuming way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved by using [chuckt](https://github.com/epixa/chuckt-node).

```
npm install chuckt
```

In the source code of the server:

```
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var chuckt = require('chuckt');

var sock = sockjs.createServer();
sock.on('connection', function(conn) {
    var chuckt = new ChuckT(conn);
    // ... do chuckt stuff like add listeners or emit events
```

In the client:

```
<script src="chuckt.js"></script>
<script>
    var sock = new SockJS('http://example.com/socket');
    var chuckt = epixa.chucktify(sock);
</script>
```

Be careful that `once` is not available at the moment in the client.

Comment: Does chuckt support the events when sockjs kicks in support for older browsers?

Comment: I think so. Anyway, the library is quite small, so if you'd like to support a particular browser, you should be able to make it work in a relatively easy way.

Comment: What does epixa mean?

Comment: I don't remember well, because it's an old project, but apparently it's the username of the maintainer of chuckt.